# Cannot understand why outer Promise wont resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I am a beginner to the weird ways Javascript works, and I am unable to understand the single threaded design and how Promises work.

Take the following code:

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var inn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => reject('Error'), 0);
        }).catch((msg) => console.log(msg));
    return inn;
  });
}

a().then((msg) => console.log('then'));
```

My questions are the following:

- The inner promise fails thats why I get Error printed, but why doesn't the other Promise resolve and get 'then' printed?
- Does returning a Promise from a Promise means that the outer promise resolves ?
- When I encounter a catch block does it mean the Promise is cancelled ?

Sorry if this is noob but I am unable to exactly find the answers that I looking for, most other posts are just confusing me.

Comment: Whatever is returned from a Promise constructor function is ignored. This pattern offers no benefit.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yeah, but I did this to try to understand the Javascript event loop a little better.

Comment: Yes I know, and now you understand a little more :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `new Promise` within another `new Promise` is an antipattern, and what you experience here is a reason why.

You don't call any of the `resolve` and `reject` of the outer `new Promise`. The `return inn` has no effect, because the outer `new Promise` is only resolved or rejected, by either calling `resolve`, `reject` or by an error that is thrown, and neither of this is happening there.

That's how it should look like:

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject('Error'), 0);
  }).catch((msg) => console.log(msg));
}

a().then((msg) => console.log('then'));
```

You only use `new Promise` if you need to convert something async that does not provide a Promise as a result, into a Promise. And you want to keep the code footprint within that `new Promise` as small as possible, so that you can be sure that every code path will lead to either a resolve ar reject condition.

So turning a `setTimeout` into a Promise by wrapping it into a `new Promise` is fine. But at that point, you have a `Promise`, so there is no need to wrap that into another `new Promise`. That breaks the whole purpose of chaining and the guarantees Promises make. ([What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it))

And you should not use strings as errors. Neither for `throw` nor for `reject` use `reject(new Error('Error'))` (or a custom error object) instead.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is an anti-pattern (with an example if possible)?

Comment: @AdityaBhave why would you use a promise inside a promise? Kills the purpose of promise chaining.

Comment: Hmm ... makes sense ... I am not able to think of a suitable usecase for it.

Comment: @AdityaBhave `I am not able to think of a suitable use case for it.` there is absolutely no use case. Every use case you might come up with can most certainly be translated from  `new Promise((…) => { new Promise((…) => {…}) })` to a `new Promise((…) => {…}).then((…) => new Promise( (…) => {… }))` and if not then its locially broken in some way.

Comment: @t.niese I am exploring this nested pattern because I want to understand about Promise behavior.

Comment: @ng.newbie you shouldn't try to explore behavior that is not an intended use case. It's like - bad comparison incoming - figuring out how a padlock behaves, if you _"lock"_ the fence close by instead of the gate .

Comment: @t.niese I get it. But I am actually trying to wrap my head around how Microtasks work in the Javascript event loop.

Comment: @ng.newbie but even then you shouldn't do that. The `(resolve, reject) => ...` callback you pass to a `new Promise` is called immediately, and has nothing to do with microtasks, only the resolving and rejecting has. You might draw the wrong conclusions out of that.

Answer (score 0):

You must `resolve` `inn` within function `a` rather than `return` it in order for the promise chain to continue unbroken.

Answer (score 0):

Because first promise is not resolved/rejected. Check following. I just changed `return inn` to `resolve(inn)`

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var inn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => reject('Error'), 0);
        }).catch((msg) => console.log(msg));
    resolve(inn);
  });
}

a().then((msg) => console.log('then'));
```